# Where can you find symbols (like these) that aren't on the legend?

Tags: navigation, canada, aeronautical-charts, symbology

I see a lot of these fan like symbols:

[image: these fan like symbols]

...on the Nav Canada Alaska Highway - Fort Nelson to Northway, 1:500,000 VFR Navigation Chart, but they're not anywhere on the map legend.

I presume they're marshland as they look a little similar to symbols I've seen on hiking maps, but I don't like assuming when making flight plans!..

Is there some universal reference somewhere that I don't know about? Are they indicating marshland, or are they something else entirely?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find this symbol in the  ["FAA Aeronautical Chart User Guide"](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/flight_info/aeronav/digital_products/aero_guide/)

on page 30.

[image]It shows as "Swamps, Marshes, Bogs"

Comment: Excuse my ignorance here, but what is a "hummock"?

Comment: hum·mock
ˈhəmək/
noun
noun: hummock; plural noun: hummocks

    a hillock, knoll, or mound.
        a hump or ridge in an ice field.
        North American
        a piece of forested ground rising above a marsh.

Comment: Answers my question, thank you! Though do you know if there's a Canadian/Nav Canada reference too? The symbols look a slightly different, and it seems odd to have to look to a foreign source for map symbols.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know.  I would check with the Canadian Aviation authority at this website https://www.tc.gc.ca/eng/air-menu.htm

Comment: Will do, thanks